# Toggle only ASCII Charager in Button Text using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On clicking button it is showing a hidden menu which I called 'User Panel'. I use the toggle script which is working fine.

All I need to do is to change the ASCII arrow to up side while toggling.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<input type="button" class="userPanelButton" value="User: Simranjit ▼" style="float:right" id="hideDisplayUserDetailsButton" />
```

Here is script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hideDisplayUserDetailsButton").click(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#hideDisplayUserDetails").slideToggle(200);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should be using CSS generated content for this in the first place – and then it is easy to “switch out” by f.e. toggling a class on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hideDisplayUserDetailsButton").click(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#hideDisplayUserDetails").slideToggle(200);

        var val = $("input#hideDisplayUserDetailsButton").val();
        var val1 = $("input#hideDisplayUserDetailsButton").val();
        val = val.slice(0,-1);

        if(val1.slice(-1) === "▼"){
            $("input#hideDisplayUserDetailsButton").val(val + "▲");
        }
        else{
            $("input#hideDisplayUserDetailsButton").val(val + "▼");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I only tested in Safari, Chrome and IE. Both on mobile and Desktop.